# Can Preview on Mountain Lion make animated pictures from a sequence of PNG?

Tags: macos, preview

I seem to recall making animated GIF from Preview.app on earlier OS, but can't find the options to make a GIF on the latest version of the app.

Can I use 10.8 Preview to make animated PNG or GIF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you hold down alt/option when you click the format dropdown in the export menu, you can still select GIF in Mountain Lion. Once you have done this, you can continue with the normal animated gif creation process:

- Save your image as a GIF
- Show the sidebar
- Drag additional frames on top of the thumbnail

Comment: This is so awesome - once I had saved all 4 images as gif with the not-visually-obvious manner of exporting the PNG, your steps are spot on for making an animated gif. Now I need to work on the quality as the gif has big artifacts and moves too fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Lion, the Save/Export to GIF (and some other formats) has been hidden away, you need to option-click the *Format* menu in the Save dialog to find it.

I tried to follow [these directions](http://blog.iharder.net/2009/10/22/gif-create-animated-gifs-with-mac-os-x-preview-app/) for creating animated GIFs, but I wasn't able to add more than one frame. Perhaps with a bit more persistence that will help though, I may have missed something in my quick attempt.

Comment: I was able to combine multiple GIF images into a single automated GIF under OSX 10.7.5 today.  One trick is that the default thumbnail pane was a "tree" that needed to be expanded by clicking on the triangle.  Also, for deleting frames, the Delete option is in the Edit menu (not the right-click context menu).